# List welcome email not firing

Tags: marketing-cloud

Has anyone run in to problems with list welcome emails not firing when new records are added?

I have one set up on All Subscribers but when a new record is added (regardless of source) the email does not send. Typically I use Triggered Send definitions and will likely pursue that but wondering if anyone has encountered this specific problem and found a reason/explanation/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this would be due to adding subscribers through a method other than Web Collect or the standard Subscription Center. As per the [documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/solution_guides/welcome_email/):

> Welcome email does not currently support imports, manually-created
> subscribers, Smart Capture, or API.

If you are adding through one of the two allowed methods, another possible reason it is not working is because your triggered email interaction isn't active. Each list Welcome Email automatically creates a triggered email interaction that can be manually managed through the Interactions tab. Here you can review the status as well as see if any emails are queued / errored.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, Anon! Subscribers are currently being added by one of those unsupported methods.

Comment: Hi Anon, I ran in the same issue. I tried to access the documentation link that you have provided here but it no longer exists. I am aware that Salesforce is ending support for welcome emails starting 2020, but does welcome email using list still work? You mentioned that import option is not supported, it was one and a half year back, is the option still not supported? I tried searching for an official documentation on it but could not find any. Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think the documentation was temporarily down. It should load now, and it still states the same limitations. Considering it is nearing retirement I would be very surprised if any additional support was added, it is primarily left for legacy reasons at this point as SF tries to push everyone into Journey Builder.